# c# How to add a treeNode to a treeView without duplication

Tags: c#, treeview

**I get nothing displayed on my treeView when I run the script below.  I think that I am missing something. all the variables are defined**

```
        if (files != null)
        {
            int check = 0;
            string[] array= null;
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in files)
            {
                if (treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= treeView1.Nodes.Count; i++)
                    {
                        array[i] = treeView1.Nodes[i].Name;
                    }
                    for (int m = 0; m <= treeView1.Nodes.Count; m++)
                    {
                        if (array[m] == file.DirectoryName)
                        {
                            check++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (check == 0)
                    {
                        treeView1.Nodes.Add(file.DirectoryName);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Silly Question, but there are some nodes in the tree before this executes?

Comment: and at least one file in files, in fact have you considered debugging it?

Comment: Your array looks empty, too.

Comment: Getting unique DirectoryNames first would be good. A class to hold what's in the tree would be good as well. "Our customers don't like trees, you should use a ListView", will be a nervous breakdown given your approach.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, The tree is empty before the excute. And I have "files" as "files= root.getfiles();" in soewhere above. And I am realy thinking of using listView. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @LarsTech, Yes, it is empty at the very begining of the excution. But it will start having some elements on the go, I mean when it walk the directories of my local machine. Thanks :)

Comment: **I wish the idea is clear that not having any thing displayed on my treeview.  I spent about 7 hours tryig to get result but I couldn't do so. THANKS ALL**

Comment: First line of code is If nodes.count > 0. So empty tree is do nothing, add a root node to it. say "My Files", or get rid of that if statement, so your code updates the tree with files it hasn't got, which appears to be what you are aiming at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got the answer to my question! And have every thing displayed appropriately.**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo Root = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
        // treeView1.Nodes.Add("Local Disk");
        WalkDirectoryTree(Root);

        treeView1.PathSeparator = @"\";
        PopulateTreeView(treeView1, paths, '\\');


        DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
        {
            if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
           {
                if (Drive.IsReady == true)
                {
                    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(Drive.Name);
                    node.Tag = Drive;
                    WalkDirectoryTree(Drive.RootDirectory);

                    treeView2.PathSeparator = @"\";
                    PopulateTreeView(treeView2, paths, '\\');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //**************************************************************************************************

    List<string> paths = new List<string>();
    private void FullPath(string str)
    {
        paths.Add(str);
    }
    //**************************************************************************************************

    void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

        // First, process all the files directly under this folder 
        try
        {
            files = root.GetFiles("*.lst");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            log.Add(e.Message);
        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
            {

                FullPath(fi.DirectoryName);
            }

            subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

            foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
            {
                WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    //**************************************************************************************************


    private static void PopulateTreeView(TreeView treeView, IEnumerable<string> paths, char pathSeparator)
    {
        TreeNode lastNode = null;
        string subPathAgg;
        foreach (string path in paths)
        {
            subPathAgg = string.Empty;
            foreach (string subPath in path.Split(pathSeparator))
            {
                subPathAgg += subPath + pathSeparator;
                TreeNode[] nodes = treeView.Nodes.Find(subPathAgg, true);
                if (nodes.Length == 0)
                    if (lastNode == null)
                        lastNode = treeView.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                    else
                        lastNode = lastNode.Nodes.Add(subPathAgg, subPath);
                else
                    lastNode = nodes[0];
            }
            lastNode = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be some code I'd use for quick-n-dirty prototyping. Hopefully it will get you started.

```
List<DirectoryInfo> dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\windows").Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d)).ToList();    
List<FileInfo> files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\windows", "*.*").Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToList(); 
if (dirs != null) treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(dirs.Select(d => new TreeNode() { Text = d.FullName }).ToArray());
if (files != null) treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(files.Select(f => new TreeNode() { Text = f.FullName }).ToArray());
```

Comment: **Access is denied!!.  I am running this to walk my local machine directories.  Thanks**

Comment: I am trying to get the whole C: drive. THANKS